# Java 1.4.2 - Class Variables

Tags: java, file-io

I have a simple program in progress that needs the declaration lines

> read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marks.txt"));

and

> line = read.readLine();

to be class variables. How would I do this?

Here is the code I wrote so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class WriteKong
{
    public static String line;
    public static BufferedReader read;
public static PrintWriter write;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {       
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marks.txt"));
            line = read.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            read.readLine();
        }
    }

    public static void sort()
    {
    // THIS IS WHAT THE FUNCTION DOES:
    //  > check the fourth digit in the line
    //  > if there is no fourth digit then store the mark
    //  > if mark is less than 50 then write to "fail.txt"
    //  > if mark is 50 or greater then write to "pass.txt"


    }

}
```

EDIT: I want these variables to be declared as a class variable. I don't want to go through the pain of redefining the same variables in all of the methods I use.

Comment: If you'll Google "java readline" you'll find plenty of examples...

Comment: `line` and `read` are already class members.. whats the question?

Comment: Read Class variables http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Just remember if they are class variables (statics) their visibility is the entire class file.  if you modify them in a method they are modified globally.   Not sure if this would be the behavior you would want.

Answer (score 2):

They are class variables in your code. The code satisfies the requirements given.

If you're confused why your loop does not read all the lines from the file it's because you never assign the newly read line to to `line`.